# Controlling order of ajax calls with redux-saga

Tags: redux-saga

I have an interaction with a checkbox which should fire off an http request everytime the checkbox is clicked.

I would like each call to be run after the previous call finishes.

My feeling is that redux-saga would be perfect for this, but I'm not understanding how to model this interaction.

If I use `call`, anything request coming in will be ignored, until the

If I use `fork`, the calls will all go at the same time. It is unclear to me if/how to wait for task to finish. Will `yield task` do that?

I see that channels can "buffer" requests, but it's unclear to me how to use channels in this way.

Comment: it seems that 1st example from [channel doc](https://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/Channels.html) should do exactly what you want to accomplish. Can you perhaps elaborate a bit more what part of channel usage is not clear to you?

Comment: What if had wanted a different "actionChannel" for each entity. Meaning it would be ok if the requests where concurrent for different entities, but need to be synchronous for any particular entity.

Comment: do you want *all interactions to cause http requests?  or do you want to take the latest, once the previous call is done?  you're right that you should use channels for this.  

to answer your follow-up question:  you could just have an object mapping keys (corresponding to entities) to channels.  it would be slightly tricky since each time you see a new key, you'd want to spawn a new saga.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `takeLatest` helper.

```
function* runRequest(action) {
  const status = action.payload;
  yield call(api, status ? 'on' : 'off');
}

function* rootSaga() {
  yield* takeLatest(CHECKBOX_CHANGED, runRequest);
}
```

`takeLatest` helper is useful if you want to start HTTP request every specified action is dispatched and the previous request is cancelled before a new one started.

Here is an official documentation: http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/basics/UsingSagaHelpers.html

Comment: I don't want the previous one cancelled. I want them all to run, just in order.

Comment: Umm... when you send request A, B, C in this order, you want to receive responses the same order as requests, even if you receive a response of B first, right?

Comment: I don't particularly care about the responses, but I do need B to start only after A finishes, and same for C.

Comment: I got it. But what is the difference between a usecase of "actionChannel" and your requirement? It can be used for buffering incoming actions and start a request one by one.

http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/Channels.html#using-the-actionchannel-effect